# How can I apply volume cube node with texture effect to different kinds of geometry?

Tags: geometry-nodes, volumetrics

[image]

I found this volume cube node is helpful with making the sponge-like structure. However, I can only apply this effect on the cube. How can I apply this effect to others geometry, like cylinder?

Answer (score 1):

For simple figures like a cylinder, you can check if the position of a voxel from top-down view is inside a circle. You can compare the result with texture using multiply or boolean and:

[image]

Sphere is easy also:

[image]

You can try to get more complex shapes like torus:

[image]

If you want to use a complex object, that hardly can be described using math, you can use boolean operation:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps me a lot!

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//blender.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Blender way of saying thank you.